# XMLEvent to String for logging

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax

I am using Stax. I have to log any current `XMLEvent`, when something goes wrong. If I use `toSting()`, I get something like `[Stax Event #1]`. Is there any way/tool to get readable and clear `String` representation of `XMLEvent`?

Answer (score 0):

For now I use `org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(event, SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE)`.